# Unable To Change CSS JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just want to set display property of one of my div to block based on event, by default its 'none'
Its not happening with error: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined 
Below is my code. Please suggest.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sample Mod Pop UP</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
</head>
<body class="body">


<div class="popUp" id="id1">
  <p>Are You Sure You Want to Quit?</p>
  <span>&#10006</span> 
</div>
<button onClick=closeWindown() class="btn">Close</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function closeWindown(){

    document.getElementsByClassName("popUp").style.display="block";


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` gets a nodeList, so you have to iterate

```
function closeWindown(){

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("popUp");

    for (var i=elements.length; i--;) {
        elements[i].style.display = "block";
    }

}
```

As a sidenote, `querySelectorAll('.popup')` has better support, but is non-live.